# How can I get the number of relationships in the ontology using OWL-API

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I wanna get the total number of relationships between classes (just classes without taking into account individuals) in an ontology, I'm not sure if I can get it through the metrics that provides protege. I'll put an example below to show you what I'm looking for. 
[image]
This picture represents an excerpt of people ontology. For me the total number of relationshiphs between classes is 11 (8 subclass relationships and 3 other relationships ). 
By visualizing the ontology metrics provided by protege, this is what I get (in the picture below):  [image] As you can see I have just 5 subclassOf axioms instead of 8. And I don't know if it's possible to get the total number of relationships from only those metrics. I wanna get the total number using java code based on OWL-API. I use Protege just to have an idea of numbers of metrics. 
Please if you have any idea that may help me to get the total number, I would be grateful

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can count axioms of a specific type with `OWLOntology::getAxioms(AxiomType)` - I believe that's what Protege is doing - but I don't think that will be enough for your objective. EquivalentClasses axioms with more than two elements in it will count for more than one link, for example.